# Basics - HTML and Python Connection with bottle

Tags: python, html, bottle

I am newbie on Python. I know C, I've been trying to figure Python out and I succeeded a little bit, I can write some little programs with it. I also know HTML basics and did some basic websites with it.

I have an assignment with these two. I need to do a website that user can post some messages with some attachments, can rate, delete or filter existing messages, and users also should be able to choose the appearance of the website. And I am allowed to do it only with "bottle" and Python 3.4.

So, how is this possible to connect those two different languages, HTML and Python? I know how the server, request and response relations work but I could'nt find any basic stuff on internet about it. How is it possible to do a website using python bottle? I understand the need of python for a website but how to use it? I mean, is there any import on HTML like "import website.py" that I can mention the Python file in my HTML to use it, or vice versa. The thing I need to learn is how to connect python file and html file so that I have a website that uses some python codes inside?

Please explain everything just like talking to a 10 year old boy with a clear English, because I saw some information on web like full of codes and could not even understand how does those bottle codes work.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In essence HTML is text. Each time the browser makes a **request** (for example to `http://localhost:8080/login` or `www.domain.com/route`) some server has to serve this html text document.

If your HTML never changes(static website) then you don't need Python. But if you need to generate new HTML for new requests (for example including values from a Database which could change in time) then a Python program can help combine a basic **HTML template** (imagine normal html with some placeholders for variables)  with the new info (for example inserting variable values) and **render** the new HTML website.

Bottle is a Python library that enhances basic Python capabilities by having convenience methods to handle routes, sessions, etc. For example if you have a template that looks like this in file called `hello_template.tpl`(note the change html->tpl):

**hello_template.tpl**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World in Bottle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello {{name.title()}}!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

then you can render it with the variable `name` like this from your `server.py` file:

**server.py**

```
from bottle import route, template, run

@route('/hello')
@route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name='World'):
    return template('hello_template', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

by running in the console:

```
python server.py
```

If you then go to `http://localhost/alex:8080` the bottle server will read the template `hello_template.tpl`, fill it with the name Alex and return it to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. But my question is how to use them together? I understand the logic but don't know anything about syntax, how can I use a e.g. "mysite.html" file with "mycode.py" together?

Comment: Yes, you would have those two files(rename html to tpl) and then you run, python mycode.py. Then you go with the browser to localhost:8080 and you will see the page. See my update and tell me if there is something you are still missing.

Comment: If I understood correctly, when I go to `http://localhost/name` then it triggers the python file, it reads the name and puts it in the template file wherever necessary as you said, and shows me the template filled with `name`. With `@route('/hello/<name>')` we said that whatever user writes after `http://localhost/` will be accepted as `name`, but we wrote in definition in python that `hello(name='World')`, how our `name` changed the `world` in definition and what would happen if we wouldn't write `World` or anything in there?

Comment: yes, that is an example of bottle handling a route. It would return a HMTL file to the browser, i.e. the template rendered with the variable name. The `name='World'` is somewhat optional and is really a detail in the big picture(specifies the default value of name for the function `hello` if name is not given). It would be the same if I just put only `name`.

Comment: I got it, but what if I want to put a message form in HTML body? How can I express it that it will be an area that Python will fill it?

Comment: This is already getting too specific for the scope of this question. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your original problem. I recommend you take a look at [the Bottle documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#http-request-methods) or ask new question explaining the problem your are trying to solve now.